# Recorded Audio is not clear

Tags: android, audio

I am recording the audio in Android using AudioRecorder, I have issue that I recorded a song but pitch and running of frequency is too fast that result to bad sound. How can I fix this ?

```
// convert short to byte
private byte[] short2byte(short[] sData) {
    int shortArrsize = sData.length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[shortArrsize * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < shortArrsize; i++) {
        bytes[i * 2] = (byte) (sData[i] & 0x00FF);
        bytes[(i * 2) + 1] = (byte) (sData[i] >> 8);
        sData[i] = 0;
    }
    return bytes;

}

public AudioRecord findAudioRecord() {
    for (int rate : mSampleRates) {
        for (short audioFormat : new short[]{AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT}) {
            for (short channelConfig : new short[]{AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO}) {
                try {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Attempting rate " + rate + "Hz, bits: " + audioFormat + ", channel: "
                            + channelConfig);
                    bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, channelConfig, audioFormat);

                    if (bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                        // check if we can instantiate and have a success
                        recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, rate, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);
                        if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)
                            return recorder;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, rate + "Exception, keep trying.", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

where rate = 44100 , channel config = 16, buffer size = 4096, PCM_ENCODING_16_BIT

```
private void writeAudioDataToFile() {
// Write the output audio in byte
String filePath = "/sdcard/8k16bitMono.wav";

short sData[] = new short[bufferSize / 2];

try {
    os = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
while (isRecording) {
    // gets the voice output from microphone to byte format
    recorder.read(sData, 0, bufferSize / 2);
    System.out.println("Short writing to file" + sData.toString());
    try {
        // writes the data to file from buffer stores the voice buffer
        byte bData[] = short2byte(sData);

        os.write(bData, 0, bufferSize);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: ARe you playing the recorded file with your app, or with any player?

Comment: I played with a player or from my app also but same thing like voice is changing like cartoon

Comment: The problem is most probably related to the samplerate. For example if your recording has been made at 22050 HZ but is being played at 44100, your audio would sound like the chipmunks. This could also happen if a mono recording is being played as stereo.

Comment: Yes, it seems to me that problem is mismatching I was playing with stereo because that tool have only that option, Can you suggest any tool that I can play in mono

Comment: Why don't you remove AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO from your allowable formats?

Comment: yes I tried but some noise was there in the sound, I need to capture sound very clear

Comment: You are creating a file with a .wav extension but no wave header; if player software accepts this at all, it will be left to *guess* at the format and rate of the data.  Naturally you should expect poor results from such guesses.  Either write a proper wave header, or use player software which knows the sample rate and formatting of your data.

Comment: Also you appear to be trying an 8-bit format first, and if that succeeds you will go with it, but it appears likely your code will still try to convert the samples as if they were 16 bit.

Comment: @Merlevede Thank you So MUCH!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting these values for your **MediaRecorder**

```
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION );
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
```

This kind of made the audio quality better for me!

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. It works.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    Button play,stop,record;

    private MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder;
    private String outputFile = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        record=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        stop.setEnabled(false);
        play.setEnabled(false);
        outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.3gp";;

        myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

        record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {
                    myAudioRecorder.prepare();
                    myAudioRecorder.start();    

                }catch (IllegalStateException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                record.setEnabled(false);
                stop.setEnabled(true);


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myAudioRecorder.stop();
                myAudioRecorder.release();
                myAudioRecorder  = null;

                stop.setEnabled(false);
                play.setEnabled(true);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio recorded successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();

                try {
                    m.setDataSource(outputFile); 
                }catch (IOException e){

                    e.printStackTrace();                
                }

                try {

                    m.prepare();                    

                } catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                m.start();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```